# Javascript AJAX working but not able to retrieve the object from response received

Tags: javascript

I have tried following script in Java script,

```
// Below is the Ajax call for get http methods
function callAjaxGet(url, callback){
    var xmlhttp;
    // compatible with IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
            console.log(xmlhttp['responseJSON']);
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseJSON);
            callback(xmlhttp.responseJSON);
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

I am not able to get the xmlhttp.responseJSON, it is getting populated in the response, I can see it in firebug window. but not able to access it.

I am using above function by calling the following one.

```
window.onload = function() {
    url = "/user/getAll";
    var data = callAjaxGet(url, function(responseJSON) {
        // on success call back.
        console.log(responseJSON);
    });
}
```

I been searching for this last couple of hours but no success yet.

Comment: no logging doesn't work, I see `undefined` but I can see it in logging if I print the whole xmlhttp object as responseJSON

Comment: define your `.onreadystatechange` **after** using `.open(...)` ...

Comment: @KarelG doesn't work

Comment: if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200){
            console.log('+++++++++++++++++++++++++++');
            console.log(xmlhttp['responseJSON']);
            console.log(xmlhttp.responseJSON);
            callback(xmlhttp.responseJSON);
        }
    

here you added both status and readystate change, use only one status to get the response, also console log the readystate, atleast you should get which state you are receiving

Comment: [`responseJSON` is not part of the XMLHttpRequest specification](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#handler-xhr-onreadystatechange). Use either `response`, `responseText` or `responseXML`

Comment: @AndréDion Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
// Below is the Ajax call for get http methods
function callAjaxGet(url, callback){
    // compatible with IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){

            callback(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
        }
    }
    xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: why JSON.parse(this.responseText) ? can't I use this.responseJSON only? btw I tried this it prints only undefined.

Comment: I mean the questions which I asked you  in above comment, I guess your answer is the correct one. :)